# why using kubectl patch rollingupdate-strategy doesn't restart the pod

Tags: kubernetes

i found a phenomenon that when i use such patch command and all pods managed by nginx1 deployment do not restart and the strategy for deployment was updated;

```
kk patch deployments.apps nginx1 --type json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/strategy/rollingUpdate/maxUnavailable","value":100%}]'
```

Also i have read some documents in k8s.io ,but not found more details in `patch`;
so i suppose that unless using patch change the properties under pod-template ,the pod will still alive?
Maybe it's wrong, waiting for your comments,ths!

Answer (score 0):

Pods recreates only if you update any fields under template configuration

`spec.template` or `spec.template.spec`